# Fetch all need to solve

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$db;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);
return $db;

# Get all users in pot
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `currentPot`');
$currentPotArr = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and I've got error like this :

> [Fri Dec 11 07:57:35.260326 2015] [:error] [pid 2274] [client
>   89.64.51.139:32356] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in
>   /home/admin/domains/csbox.pl/public_html/php/update.php on line 21,

referer: http://csbox.pl/

Why?

Php 5.6.16
Apache 2.4.17
DirectAdmin 1.49.1
MySQL 5.6.12

On the site also iv'e got an php/update.php 500 (Internal Server Error) error

Comment: can you please show you table structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: There you go http://scr.hu/9li8/lehf2

Comment: Why do you return when there is no function and fetchall is used after execute

Comment: On the site also iv'e got an php/update.php 500 (Internal Server Error) error. Your answer is not helping me. Becouse ive got this error on new hosting and on old hosting it was working.

Comment: your `$db->query()` call returns a boolean false, so there is a problem with the query. Run `print_r($db->errorInfo());` and see what the problem is.

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )

Answer (score 0):

Your PDO statement and fetching results seems to be all right. 
one thing I noticed ,

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$db;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass); return $db;

why you writing  "return $db". Does it is inside function?
Just remove "return $db;" if it is not a fuction.

Comment: If that were the problem the line throwing the error wouldn't even be executed.

Comment: it will through error, if you a call a function on non-object variable. 
 see "Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean"  that mean $db was  Boolean . its values can be TRUE.

Comment: True, but if the code returned in the return line the function wouldn't even be called. Obviously the provided code is not the full code.

Comment: I agree with your statement. he probably need to paste full function in order to  find out what really causing fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

Perhaps the query is returning false? (Your error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean).

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php